# Where can I change the color of the vertical tab labels in Blender?

Tags: interface, color

Where can I change the color of the vertical tab labels of the N-panel in Blender? (red marked square)

[image]

Comment: You can't unless you mess with the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These vertical Tabs are adjusted *per editor*.
For 3D Viewport, it's in *Properties > Themes > 3D Viewport > Theme Space*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Properties > Themes > 3D Viewport > Theme Space > Region Text*.

Answer (score 0):

If you like your settings, you can copy them via the eyedropper (in theme preferences), for instance, from the 3D Viewport to the Node Editor.

Comment: If you want to delete your answer, please do so through the "Delete" option rather than removing the content with an edit